# Java Android Runtime.getRuntime().exec()

Tags: java, android, android-pendingintent, runtime.exec

I'm working on an app where I want to run an android shell command using:

`Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("input keyevent 85");`

This should start/stop the music player for me, **and it works when I'm currently on my app.**
The way I do it is to set a **prepared intent** beforehand at a certain time, so I can have the music playing in a few minutes.

However, it doesn't work when I have the app running in the background. The intents do print out my Log.i messages in Logcat, so I'm not sure where the problem lies. Perhaps it is a permission problem?

Comment: Apparently: `Input event injection from pid 9182 permission denied`
Meaning it was indeed a permission problem.. is there an alternative to stopping/playing the music currently in the media player without relying on the mediaplayer module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, using this method, the APK would have to be signed, the device rooted and the APP be placed in the directory of system apps.